# Reporting Options in SharePoint 2019 - SSRS and everything else

Tags: sharepoint-server, task-list, reporting-services, reporting

Having not touched SharePoint since SharePoint 2013, I was trying to understand what options are available/provided with `SharePoint 2019` in regards to reporting along with `SQL Server 2019`.

### Question(s)

Is there anywhere with a definitive listing of Report offerings in SharePoint 2019? (or can we add them to this post?)

Whilst previous experience was custom reports via Report Builder - I want to look at report offerings (and visualisations) around lists, tasks, and workflows too.

### Previous versions

Previously I've used and installed SSRS along with SharePoint (2010/2013) to allow reports to be created using Report Builder (RDLs) and the RDLs uploaded to SharePoint where they could be viewed.

I've jumped through a lot of articles and am a little confused about what we can do reports-wise in SharePoint 2019.

### Confusions for reference

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/install-report-builder?view=sql-server-ver15

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/install-the-first-report-server-in-sharepoint-mode?view=sql-server-2016&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2019

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-sharepoint/powershell-cmdlets-for-reporting-services-sharepoint-mode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-2016#bkmk_basic_samples

> Reporting Services integration with SharePoint is no longer available after SQL Server 2016.

[https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-report-or-a-scorecard-sharepoint-server-1b0cff41-d6a6-47ae-a908-8fa1b4ca4379#:~:text=1%20Determine%20what%20information%20you%20want%20to%20show,PerformancePoint%20Dashboard%20Designer%2C%20Visio%2C%20and%20more.%20See%20More](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-report-or-a-scorecard-sharepoint-server-1b0cff41-d6a6-47ae-a908-8fa1b4ca4379#:%7E:text=1%20Determine%20what%20information%20you%20want%20to%20show,PerformancePoint%20Dashboard%20Designer%2C%20Visio%2C%20and%20more.%20See%20More)

> SQL Server Reporting Services - Reporting Services makes it possible to create and share a wide range of powerful reports, including interactive maps, bubble charts, gauges, tables, and other views. Reporting Services report creation tools include Power View (launched from SharePoint Server), Report Designer, and Report Builder.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-sharepoint/report-viewer-web-part-sharepoint-site?view=sql-server-ver15

> The Report Viewer web part was available as part of the Reporting Services Add-in for SharePoint products. The web part was specific for report servers in SharePoint integrated mode. SharePoint integrated mode was deprecated after SQL Server 2016.

> Starting with SQL Server 2017, there's only one installation mode for Reporting Services: Native mode. You could embed all reports types using a Page Viewer web part using the rs:Embed=true URL parameter. Embedding reports into SharePoint pages is an integration story requested by customers and the updated Report Viewer web part enables this scenario for paginated reports.

https://boredadmin.com/sharepoint-2019-ssrs-integration-1/

> Officially SSRS Integrated mode is deprecated in SQL Server 2017 and SharePoint 2019, Now It is not a part of the SQL Server 2017. However, organizations could continue to use SSRS versions 2017 in SharePoint 2019. This is not supported in SharePoint 2019, which means that integrated mode isn’t an option at all with SharePoint 2019.
> But the good news is, there is some workaround to integrate SSRS 2017 with SharePoint 20149 using the report viewer web part.

Comment: Putting this link in as a holding comment for now whilst I explore different solutions https://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2018/08/business-intelligence-sharepoint-2019/

Comment: A list of deprecated features https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/what-s-new/what-s-deprecated-or-removed-from-sharepoint-server-2019

Answer (score 0):

As I know, from "Sharepoint <-> SSRS" perspective, the only available option is to install *SQL Server Reporting services* in **Native mode** on a separate server. And deploy all rdl-reports to that server, not SharePoint libraries. (technically you could probably install SSRS native to SharePoint servers on different ports, but I haven't tested it).

Then you can use the *Page Viewer* webpart or the *Report Viewer* webpart (which now comes as a separate wsp solution) to display these rdl-reports from SSRS "native" server in an iframe-like style.

I.e. for SharePoint 2019 there is no any option to render rdl-reports that stored in SharePoint libraries. And there is no any kind of SSRS *SharePoint-integrated* mode and *Reporting Services SharePoint service application*.

---

For SharePoint 2016 however you can still use SQL Server 2016 installation media that contains *Reporting Services - **SharePoint integrated** mode* to install SSRS service and service application on SharePoint servers without using any *SSRS Native* installation.